# How to find processor speed on Linux w/throttling

Tags: linux

My `/proc/cpuinfo` says my processor is 800Mhz, when I know the thing is actually 2.8Ghz.  This is due to idle throttling where the cpu clock is slowed when idle to save power.

Is there a way in Linux to find the **true** cpu speed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq` contains the maximum frequency in KHz (that directory, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`, also contains a bunch of other cpu-frequency related information). It contains just a single ASCII number, so is much easier to parse than the stuff in /proc/cpuinfo or the dmesg output.

Note that this info is *per-cpu*, but of course maximum frequency will be the same for all cpus on most systems, so I just used `cpu0`.

BTW, on my system, the maximum frequency can be read by any user, but the *current* frequency (*...*`/cpuinfo_cur_freq`) can only be read by root; I don't know if this is true on all systems...

Comment: What systems does this work for?  It worked for me on CentOs, but file does not exist on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @Fixee I think it should work on any reasonably mainstream linux system.  I don't know exactly when it was added, but this feature seems to have been around for ages.  A few guesses: (1) maybe the cpufreq kernel module isn't loaded; try installing the `cpufrequtils` package (that's the Debian package name, but I'd guess Ubuntu is similar), or (2) maybe they're mounting the `sysfs` filesystem someplace other than `/sys`; try `df -a -t sysfs` to see where it's mounted.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out using `grep` and `dmesg`:

```
# dmesg | grep CPU
...
CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         860  @ 2.80GHz stepping 05
...
```

Comment: Unf the analogous line for me (CentOs 6, 2.6.32-71.el6.x86 kernel), is `CPU0: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4184 stepping 01`.

Comment: As an aside, the info above (CPU0: ...) appears in /proc/cpuinfo as "model name" here.

Answer (score 0):

`lshal | grep info.product|grep GHz`